# title bar is missing in YUI

Tags: javascript, yui, yui-editor

I'm using the YUI Rich Text editor on my site. I'm loading it using the load javascript from Google. When I try to create a link (or any other action that creates an "settings" box, the title bar is missing, see [picture here](http://img150.imageshack.us/i/missing.png/). You can see how it supposed to look over [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/editor/code_editor.html) at Yahoos site for YUI.

I'm using this code in the `<head>`-tag:

```
<!--Include YUI Loader: --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/yui/2.7.0/build/yuiloader/yuiloader-min.js"></script> 
<!--Use YUI Loader to bring in your other dependencies: --> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
// Instantiate and configure YUI Loader: 
(function() { 
    var loader = new YAHOO.util.YUILoader({ 
        base: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/yui/2.7.0/build/", 
        require: ["editor"], 
        loadOptional: true, 
        combine: false, 
        filter: "MIN", 
        allowRollup: true, 
        onSuccess: function() { 
            var Editor = new YAHOO.widget.Editor('content', {
                height: '300px',
                width: '802px',
            dompath: true, //Turns on the bar at the bottom
            animate: true //Animates the opening, closing and moving of Editor windows   
            });
            Editor.render(); 
    }     
});    

// Load the files using the insert() method. 
loader.insert(); 
})(); 
</script>
```

And in my webpage:

```
<div class="sIFR-ignore yui-skin-sam">
    <textarea name="content" id="content" cols="50" rows="10">
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some help from David Glass, one of the developers of YUI RTE. The error I had make was actually an CSS thing, some where in my CSS-files it was a line that read "h3 {visibility: hidden;}" which made this error. Any how, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing your own title for the editor:

```
var Editor = new YAHOO.widget.Editor('content', {
                height: '300px',
                width: '802px',
            dompath: true, //Turns on the bar at the bottom
            animate: true //Animates the opening, closing and moving of Editor windows   
            });
            Editor._defaultToolbar.titlebar="<b>Use my title</b>";
            Editor.render();
```

Comment: sorry for that, no clue on what could be happening =(

Answer (score -1):

I might be wrong here but, due to [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) (Same Origin Policy) I don't think JavaScript hosted in Google will be able to modify the DOM (unless you are google).

Try placing JavaScript in your web server and linking from there:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://your.web.server.com/yui/2.7.0/build/yuiloader/yuiloader-min.js"></script>
```